# What is "depriving" in this sentence meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What is "depriving" in this sentence meaning?

> Viewing the activities to achieve your goals as enjoyable, fun, rewarding, etc., is more likely to produce behavior change than viewing these activities as difficult, challenging, or depriving.

Source : https://www.thehealthy.com/habits/new-year-health-mistakes/

Comment: "...thinking of the activities as being difficult, likely to challenge you or likely to deprive you of something."

Comment: It's a clumsy usage. If the writer couldn't think of a suitable single-word adjective for the final quality, he should have at least enclosed it in "scare quotes" - if only to reassure the reader that the writer does at least realise it's not an "acceptable" usage. *Doing X is difficult*, and *Doing X is challenging* are both fine, but nobody ever says *Doing X is **depriving*** (maybe ***...leads to deprivation***, but a few "creative" writers have come up with [***... is deprivational***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+deprivational%22), even if it's not in the dictionary).